# Qt5 Update MainWindow from Child Window

Tags: qt5, parent-child, signals-slots

I have two Windows in my QT Project. `MainWindow` and `Load`. I want to update some fields in `MainWindow`, when `Load` is closed. I already tried several things. I also have a function called `update_channel()` which does all the necessary things. For now, I use a `PushButton` to manually do the changes. This works fine, but I need this function to automatically be called whenever the load window is closed. For example, I tried:

```
connect(load, SIGNAL(load->close()), this, SLOT(update_channel()));
```

and

```
connect(load, &Load::update_mainwindow(), ui->pb_update, &QPushButton::click);
(with a public signal in "load.h" and emit update_mainwindow in "load.cpp")
```

I am out of ideas and I am at the point where I no longer know what to google for, none of the tips I found works in my case.

I am using Qt Creator 3.6.0 (for Qt 5.5.1)

Comment: Your windows are `QWindow`s or `QWidget`s?

Comment: MainWindow is QMainWindow, Load is QDialog

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `QDialog` class and add a signal to it call it `close`, for example. Then override the `closeEvent` member function and emit your `close` signal from there. Also, make sure that your `update_channel()` function is a slot. Then connect the `close` signal to the `update_channel` slot and you are done.

Another way is to use one of the `QDialog` existing signals: `accepted` or `rejected`. They are not exactly equivalent to the said solution but should be also acceptable since a dialog is usually either accepted or rejected.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick reply. Just one question: Where should i subclass  QDialog? In MainWindow or Load?

Comment: @Wimmal, since your Load is a `QDialog` object then it is `Load` which should become an object of the subclass

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself. The problem was not the definition of the connect statement. The Problem was the line in my code where i put this piece of code.

I put the "connect" right at the beginning of my code, where no "load" window existed.  So i changed it to:

```
load = new Load(this);
connect(load, SIGNAL(update_mainwindow()), this, SLOT(update_channel()));
load->show();
```

Now it's working as expected!